# phpbrew install php version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, apache-http-server

Im trying to get PHPbrew working, but im running onto some issues...

Everything is set right like PHPBrew requires, but i cant find the www folder where i can place my files, or set the right configuration file of for running my PHP Version.

Drupal 8 needs 5.5 to use, but 6 works only with 5.3. To switch easily, i installed php brew.

This is the command i run:

```
phpbrew install 5.5.0 +apxs2
phpbrew use 5.5.0
```

After that im getting stuck. My localhost says im using version 5.3, but when i use the command "php -v" in the terminal, it says version 5.5 cli.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You'll be using the same installation of Apache as you were using before -- no need to place your files in a separate www folder. You just need to tell Apache to use the new PHP you just built. Check your Apache configuration to see if there's a LoadModule line corresponding to your new PHP. It should look something like

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.5.0.so
```

If there is, you should be able to restart Apache and it'll work. If your LoadModule is still referring to the system php, then edit it to point to the new version, and restart Apache. More info in the documentation: https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Cookbook#apache2-support